# Prevent Pseudo Element from Triggering Scroll

Tags: css, scroll, pseudo-element

Consider [the following situation](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/QayzRq?editors=1100), in which an absolutely-positioned pseudo element triggers scroll, even though the content within the element doesn't extend past the bottom of the page (you'll probably need to view the snippet in full page mode to see what I mean):

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -50vh;
  border: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus doloremque sunt perferendis reprehenderit! Libero quaerat ipsum ad corrupti eveniet ipsa unde obcaecati officiis tenetur nobis sed in nesciunt voluptatum quidem velit reprehenderit, dolorem eum. Vero dignissimos sint sapiente architecto repudiandae nostrum quo sed! Quasi quaerat, atque nisi quae quod minima! Neque asperiores possimus deserunt impedit harum cumque quibusdam? Non dolorum voluptate vitae, perferendis et obcaecati quos fugiat inventore excepturi tempore rerum dicta. Expedita, necessitatibus iure suscipit earum, vel ipsa, repudiandae quod fugit optio consequuntur beatae dicta alias at quia perspiciatis odit totam esse soluta voluptas deserunt! Sunt vero reiciendis placeat?</div>
```

Given this situation, is there a way to prevent the pseudo element from triggering scroll even while retaining the ability of overflowing content to trigger scroll?

I'm running into this problem in [this situation](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/NXxewR?editors=1100), where I'm using Flexbox to create [a sticky footer](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) and a pseudo element to create a diagonal background color behind that footer.

I've searched both SO and Google for a solution, but failed to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to [a JS + SVG solution](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/ppyWwK) that allowed me to create the effect I needed while avoiding overflow below the footer:

```js
var footerContent = $( '.content' );

var updateTriangle = function() {
  var w = footerContent.outerWidth();
  var h = footerContent.outerHeight();
  var r = 27 / 100;
  var b = w * r;
  var B = b + h;
  var A = ( w * B ) / b;
  
  $( '.triangle' ).width( A ).height( B );
}

$( window ).on( 'resize', updateTriangle );

updateTriangle();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
}

.triangle {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 27'><defs><linearGradient id='footerBgGradient' x1='0' x2='0' y1='0' y2='1'><stop offset='0%' stop-color='%23006BA5'/><stop offset='100%' stop-color='%2300487F'/></linearGradient></defs><polygon points='0,27 100,27 100,0' fill='url(%23footerBgGradient)' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -10;
}

.content {
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border: .5rem solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Libero vero animi suscipit debitis unde mollitia veritatis sapiente maxime velit obcaecati repudiandae incidunt, corrupti, voluptates ad. Recusandae itaque doloribus quibusdam fugit ut quis cumque sit, fugiat, culpa perspiciatis mollitia inventore hic tempore aspernatur aliquam quo. Consequatur saepe a cumque! Dicta dignissimos facilis laborum impedit ad sunt quam tenetur? Repellat, officiis sed veritatis possimus ipsum, labore quam eligendi est minus quae incidunt saepe. Consequatur laudantium atque qui soluta, voluptate dolores dolore blanditiis.</div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `overflow: hidden` to the pseudo element's parent. In your demo, it is `.bottom`.

Comment: It does fix the scroll issue, but also prevents the diagonal background from being visible above the footer, which is what I need.